# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "domain_name" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, php, mautic

I have use mautic newsletter for my site.

below is my `js` code.

```
/** This section is only needed once per page if manually copying **/
if (typeof MauticSDKLoaded == 'undefined') {
    var MauticSDKLoaded = true;
    var head            = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script          = document.createElement('script');
    script.type         = 'text/javascript';
    script.src          = 'https://resources.incarta.com.au/media/js/mautic-form.js';
    script.onload       = function() {
        MauticSDK.onLoad();
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
    var MauticDomain = 'https://resources.incarta.com.au';
    var MauticLang   = {
        'submittingMessage': "Please wait..."
    }
}
```

And here is my `html`

```
   <div id="mauticform_wrapper_clicsnewsletter" class="mauticform_wrapper">
<form autocomplete="false" role="form" method="post" action="http://resources.incarta.com.au/form/submit?formId=2" id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter" data-mautic-form="clicsnewsletter">
    <div class="mauticform-error" id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter_error"></div>
    <div class="mauticform-message" id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter_message"></div>
    <div class="mauticform-innerform">


      <div class="mauticform-page-wrapper mauticform-page-1" data-mautic-form-page="1">

        <div id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter_email"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-email mauticform-field-1">
            <label id="mauticform_label_clicsnewsletter_email" for="mauticform_input_clicsnewsletter_email" class="mauticform-label">Email</label>
            <input id="mauticform_input_clicsnewsletter_email" name="mauticform[email]" value="" class="mauticform-input" type="email" />
            <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter_submit"  class="mauticform-row mauticform-button-wrapper mauticform-field-2">
            <button type="submit" name="mauticform[submit]" id="mauticform_input_clicsnewsletter_submit" name="mauticform[submit]" value="" class="mauticform-button btn btn-default" value="1">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="mauticform[formId]" id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter_id" value="2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mauticform[return]" id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter_return" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mauticform[formName]" id="mauticform_clicsnewsletter_name" value="clicsnewsletter"/>
  </form>
   </div>
```

When I try to submit my `form`, the following error shows on console:

> app.js:190 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://resources.incarta.com.au" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `https://mydomain.com.au` anywhere on your code?

Comment: Are you saying about my html code ? @PedroLobito

Comment: Does the error says `https://mydomain.com.au` or shows your real domain ?

Comment: sorry my mistake @PedroLobito

Comment: i will update my erroe plz wait @PedroLobito

Comment: ok @PedroLobito i wil trying

Comment: Also, I don't see a `src` on you `iframe`, is that correct?

Comment: yes i use emebeded code. so i frame generate automattically @PedroLobito

Comment: if you need html embeded code then i put in m question ? @PedroLobito

Comment: If it helps understanding the question, please do.

Comment: @PedroLobito now i use just i frame, and its putted here so can you see that.

Comment: @PedroLobito — CORS doesn't help with accessing cross-origin frames.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what your situation is. It sounds like "You are have a third party page in an iframe, when you submit a form in that page, you get a JS error relating to the cross-origin frame". That sounds like the third party code (which you didn't write) is not compatible with being in a cross origin frame. You need to either (1) Not use a frame or (2) Consult with the third party that wrote the code to get it changed so it will work with your frame. It isn't a problem with code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Well, running the snippet seems to load the iFrame correctly, it's just the webpage that needs some work. On the iFrame, it says the page may have moved to a new address. When I visit the page on chrome, however, it says "Your connection is not private".